# How to structure ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

At the moment I have two static array of javascript values (d1 and d2) which are then passed into a javascript object (data).

```
$(function () {

  var d1, d2, data
  d1 = [
    [1424131200000,20151],[1424217600000,22448],[1424304000000,27000],[1424390400000,30622],[1424476800000,30844],[1424563200000,23140],[1424649600000,20555]
  ]
  d2 = [
    [1424131200000,18664],[1424217600000,19149],[1424304000000,20415],[1424390400000,24617],[1424476800000,30278],[1424563200000,28808],[1424649600000,22032]
  ]

  data = [{ 
    label: "This Year", 
    data: d1
  }, {
    label: "Last Year",
    data: d2
  }]
  var holder = $('#line-chart')
  if (holder.length) {
    $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions )
  }  
})
```

I would like to change my code to achieve the same thing but load the values from two ajax calls instead of statically defining the values. But I am having troubles achieiving this. Could someone please help me with how I can modify what I have below to achieve what I have defined staticlly above.

Here is what I have so far...

```
$(function () {
  var data
  fetchData(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  }); 
  var holder = $('#line-chart')
  if (holder.length) {
    $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions )
  }  
})  

function fetchData(callback) {

    $.when(fetchThisYearsData(), fetchLastYearsData()).done(function (dataThisYear, dataLastYear) {
        var data = [];
        data.push(dataThisYear[0]);
        data.push(dataLastYear[0]);
        callback(data);
    });
}

function fetchThisYearsData() {
    return $.ajax({
          url: "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=0",
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false
        }); 
}

function fetchLastYearsData() {
    return $.ajax({
          url: "service/tranAnalysis/tranCounts.json?siteId=1&yearOffset=1",
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false
        });     
}
```

The two ajax calls return the following json...

```
{"label":"This Year","data":[[1424131200000,20151],[1424217600000,22448],[1424304000000,27000],[1424390400000,30622],[1424476800000,30844],[1424563200000,23140],[1424649600000,20555]]}

{"label":"Last Year","data":[[1424131200000,18664],[1424217600000,19149],[1424304000000,20415],[1424390400000,24617],[1424476800000,30278],[1424563200000,28808],[1424649600000,22032]]}
```

When I debug in firebug it looks like the ajax calls are happening and inside the callback function the data variable is populated. But then when I get to the call to $plot, the data variable is empty/null.

thanks

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the post to help some more. The promlem is that the $plot call shows that the data variable is empty/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those AJAX calls are *async* - so you need to do the work in the callback (else you're trying to access `data` while the AJAX call is still in progress):

```
$(function () {
    fetchData(function (data) {
        var holder = $('#line-chart')
        if (holder.length) {
            $.plot(holder, data, chartOptions )
        }  
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks appreciate that. As you can tell I'm still learning ajax.

Comment: Question for you. What is the technical name for the javascript constructs data and d1 and d2. If I had to guess d1 and d2 are javascript arrays and data is a javascript object?

Comment: The received `data` object is an Array (`[]`) and the responses from your individual AJAX calls are objects (`{}`) @Richie